# How should I say someone "let me through"?

Tags: sentence

「空港の人がもう一度搭乗券確認したと私に。。。」

通させた？ 通してあげた？
Is that right? Are there more ways of saying this?　In the most natural way possible please.

Comment: わたしに・・・させていただけませんか, わたしに・・・させてくださいませんか

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/

Comment: ありがとう、質問ではないだけど、「私に通させていただいた」とは大丈夫ですか？

Comment: 質問に　let = 過去、　"how should I ask someone to let me through" と違う。

Comment: Causative structure in Japanese can mean `make s.o. do something`,  but it can also mean `let s.o. do something`.  Example from the internet: 全部食べさせた。Made/Let (someone) eat it all.  See:http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/causepass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mean "(Someone) let me through", you can say...

> 「私を[通]{とお}した」
>   「（私を）通してくれた」

[通]{とお}した is the past tense form of the transitive verb [通]{とお}す.

---

If you want to use causative, you can say 私を通{とお}らせ(てくれ)た. The present form is 通らせる. This is the causative form of the intransitive verb 通{とお}る. (But I think [通]{とお}し(てくれ)た is more common.)

---

> 空港の人がもう一度搭乗券確認したと私に

確認**したと** is grammatically incorrect. If you're trying to say "After they checked my boarding pass one more time, they let me through", you can say...

> 空港の人は、もう一度搭乗券を確認すると、私を通し（てくれ）た。
>   空港の人は、搭乗券をもう一度確認したあと、（私を）通してくれた。

Comment: There's a lyric ♪ちょ～っと[通]{とお}してくだしゃんせ～ in a わらべ歌 (nursery song) 「通りゃんせ」

Comment: Why is it gramatically incorrect though? Also, how is 通す different from the causative form of 通る？

Comment: The conjunctive particle と for "When/If" should be attached to the dictionary form, not the past form. So it should be 確認すると. You can also say 確認したら, 確認した[後]{あと}, or 確認してから.　通す is transitive for "let ~ pass, let ~ through, pass ~ through" etc. 通らせる can mean these too, but 通す is more commonly used. And they are often uninterchangeable, eg ◎「独身を通す」「光を通す」「客を部屋に通す」✖「独身を・光を・客を部屋に通らせる」